# Asp.net mvc 5 angular 1.4 hybrid locking down views

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am looking for advice. Currently I have a mvc 5 project, very thin views and controllers and using web api 2. I am using this with angular 1.4 handling all the user interaction client side in the browser. Most gets and posts are handled between angular and web api. I like this approach as I feel I get the best of both worlds with common mvc patterns, a great JS framework, JS unit testing... I now have a requirement where there are 2 types of user role, one has access to a editable view while the other role has access to non editable views. I'm thinking of moving a lot of the angular templates back into razor to achieve this and wondered if anyone had a clean strategy for this. Basically if a user cannot access certain html elements then I don't want to send these down the wire, also I don't want to have to create separate mvc views or angular templates for the editable or non editable views....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is subjective and will result in different opinions.

With that said, I faced the same issue where I didn't want a separate view for editing and for viewing each model.  So I created an mvc helper that created am outer div with two components inside of it.  One for viewing and one for editing.  I had a common angular variable that I used for changing between editing and viewing.  The effect is the html is larger, but the cshtml is still small and readable.

like Bob mentioned in his comment it is true that a malicious user could manually switch to the editable view, but they wouldn't be able to save the changes unless their user has access (due to the restrictions that I put on updating/creating posts.

The way I see it, you only have a few options.

1. Create editable/non-editable templates in angular and get the
   correct template.
2. Make a directive that swaps the editable view
   for the non-editable view (or vice versa) when in edit mode.
3. Convert templates to razor templates and have a edit view and a
       non-edit view
4. Convert templates to razor templates and have the helper create the view that you would prefer.

After you comments, it seems like you want #3 or #4.  #4 would create 1 razor template (like mine) that would allow you to make changes to only 1 file but have it affect both views.  This might be helpful for you but depends on how consistent the markup is for the edit/non-edit views are.

example Helper for textbox and common base element(option #4)

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextboxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var dict = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes ?? new object { });
    var tag = new TagBuilder("span");//default view
    if((bool) helper.ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.CanEdit){//edit view
        tag = new TagBuilder("input");
        tag.Attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
        if (!dict.ContainsKey("type"))
        {
            tag.Attributes.Add("type", "text");//default input type
        }
    }else
    {
        var value = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(
            expression, helper.ViewData
            ).Model;
        tag.InnerHtml = value.ToString();
    }
    return BaseNode(helper, expression, tag, TagRenderMode.SelfClosing, dict);
}
public static MvcHtmlString BaseNode<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, TagBuilder tag, TagRenderMode tagRenderMode, RouteValueDictionary dict)
{
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var fullName = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);
    var id = TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(fullName);
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);


    tag.Attributes.Add("name", fullName);
    tag.Attributes.Add("id", id);

    foreach (var dKey in dict.Keys)
    {
        var value = dict[dKey].ToString();
        var key = dKey.Replace("_", "-");
        tag.Attributes.Add(key, value);
    }


    return new MvcHtmlString(tag.ToString(tagRenderMode));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bryan, that's effectively what I don't want to do, I don't want the editable html on the client, this allows the client with a bit of JS knowledge the ability to set a variable  and they have the editable view (that's what I get from your post?) Other than converting a lot of the templates back to razor I don't see any way of doing it?

Comment: @BobS I have updated my answer to give you all the options that I see and some of the code that I use (I modified it to better suit what i believe you want to do)

Comment: Thanks Bryan, option 3 seems like the safe bet but I will investigate 4 very interesting...

Comment: @Bob S, np. I like #4 